# How to add background color for a specific row or header in excel sheets using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

> How to add background color for a specific row or header in excel sheets using apache poi in the code below which was given as an example in the official giude

```
package com.raz.api.engine.apiengine.util;
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class xlGen {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Create blank workbook
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

  //Create a blank sheet
  XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(" Employee Info ");

  //Create row object
  XSSFRow row;

  //Colors
  CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
    //style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setColor(IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
    style.setFont(font);


  //This data needs to be written (Object[])
  Map < String, Object[] > empinfo = 
  new TreeMap < String, Object[] >();
  empinfo.put( "1", new Object[] { "EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION" });
  empinfo.put( "2", new Object[] { "tp01", "Gopal", "Technical Manager" });
  empinfo.put( "3", new Object[] { "tp02", "Manisha", "Proof Reader" });
  empinfo.put( "4", new Object[] { "tp03", "Masthan", "Technical Writer" });
  empinfo.put( "5", new Object[] { "tp04", "Satish", "Technical Writer" });
  empinfo.put( "6", new Object[] { "tp05", "Krishna", "Technical Writer" });

  //Iterate over data and write to sheet
  Set < String > keyid = empinfo.keySet();
  int rowid = 0;

  for (String key : keyid) {
     row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
     Object [] objectArr = empinfo.get(key);
     int cellid = 0;

     for (Object obj : objectArr) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
     }
  }
  //cell1.setCellStyle(style);


  //Write the workbook in file system
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Writesheet.xlsx"));
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  System.out.println("Writesheet.xlsx written successfully");
}
}
```

> do not read this paragraph below..
>   So i need to give some color for the header and i want to learn some features and methods which is used in the apache poi
>   In this page we will learn how to set color in our XLSX. Generally we need to set background color and font color for our rows and cell in excel file. Setting color can be used as heading or column name that increases the readability of excel file. In this example we will understand from scratch how to color in XLSX. All we need is to get an instance of CellStyle and then set the desired color to CellStyle and then assign it to XLSX cell. Create a XSSFWorkbook. Get CellStyle from XSSFWorkbook as below.

Comment: Please read [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) especially [Fills and colors](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills).

Comment: i have read but there is no method to change a color for specific row

Comment: [Row.setRowStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html#setRowStyle-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle-)

Comment: No..For w=example if i have 5 rows .I need to change only the color of the first row. Pls check my code i am getting the values from a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Always good to read: [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

In your case especially [Fills and colors](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#FillsAndFrills).

The text of your question is not really clear. But I suspect form your code sample, that the need is setting a special style to header cells.

A `CellStyle` needs to be created on workbook level. Then while creating the cells, this `CellStyle` needs to be applied to the appropriate cells using `Cell.setCellStyle`.

The following example works using the current `apache poi 4.1.1`:

```
import java.io.File;    
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class XlGen {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Create blank workbook
  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

  //Create cell style for header row
  CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
  style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.GREEN.getIndex());
  style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
  Font font = workbook.createFont();
  font.setColor(IndexedColors.YELLOW.getIndex());
  style.setFont(font);

  //Create a blank sheet
  Sheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet(" Employee Info ");

  //This data needs to be written (Object[])
  Map < String, Object[] > empinfo = 
  new TreeMap < String, Object[] >();
  empinfo.put( "1", new Object[] { "EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION" });
  empinfo.put( "2", new Object[] { "tp01", "Gopal", "Technical Manager" });
  empinfo.put( "3", new Object[] { "tp02", "Manisha", "Proof Reader" });
  empinfo.put( "4", new Object[] { "tp03", "Masthan", "Technical Writer" });
  empinfo.put( "5", new Object[] { "tp04", "Satish", "Technical Writer" });
  empinfo.put( "6", new Object[] { "tp05", "Krishna", "Technical Writer" });

  //Iterate over data and write to sheet
  Set < String > keyid = empinfo.keySet();
  int rowid = 0;

  //Create row object
  Row row;
  //Create cell object
  Cell cell;

  for (String key : keyid) {
   row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
   Object [] objectArr = empinfo.get(key);
   int cellid = 0;

   for (Object obj : objectArr) {
    cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);

    if (rowid == 1) { // it is header row
     cell.setCellStyle(style); // set style for header cells
    }
   }
  }

  for (int c = 0; c < empinfo.get("1").length; c++) {
   spreadsheet.autoSizeColumn(c);
  }

  //Write the workbook in file system
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Writesheet.xlsx"));
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  System.out.println("Writesheet.xlsx written successfully");
 }

}
```

Result:

[image]